# Removing whitespaces from data in a column

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have two columns of data in excel spreadsheet say column A and B. There are more data in column A than in column B. I am trying to find which of the data in column A is not present in column B. I use formula in column C like this  `=MATCH(A1,$B$1:$B$300,0)`. I hope to get `1`  in the row where data in column A is present somewhere in column B. Problem is that there are some white space along with the data in both the columns and match returns `#NA` for all the rows. Is there a way by which i can get rid of the white spaces? I have already tried using `TRIM` and clean on column A and B, like this `=TRIM($A$1:$A$400)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Trim` is the correct thing to use, you just aren't using it in the best way. You have two options -

1. You can use helper columns in C and D, `C1 = Trim(A1)` and `D1 = Trim(B1)` and perform the match on those columns
2. The better solution, trim the cells in the match equation like this -

`=MATCH(TRIM(A1),TRIM(B$1:B$200),0)` but make sure you enter it as an **array formula** by typing it out and then pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd> <kbd>shift</kbd> <kbd>enter</kbd>.

You'll see curly brackets in the formula bar like this - `{=MATCH(TRIM(A1),TRIM(B$1:B$200),0)}`